# CPTAxisLabel background color in Coreplot

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I want to set background color for x-axis and y-axis label. How to set the background color of CPTAxisLabel.

Answer (score 0):

Create custom axis labels. The `CPTTextLayer` class commonly used to create text labels is a subclass of `CPTBorderedLayer` so you can give it a border and/or background fill, too. Use the layer padding to adjust the margin space around the text inside the border.

Either use the `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone` labeling policy or use an axis delegate and implement the `-axis:shouldUpdateAxisLabelsAtLocations:` method. In the delegate method, create labels for each tick location and return `NO` to tell the axis that the delegate took care of updating the labels.